# Marginalize over C, can I say $\sum_c P(A,B,C)=\sum_c (P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C))=\sum_c P(A|C) \sum_c P(B|C) \sum_c P(C)$

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian-network

When reading lectures about Probabilistic Graphic Models, I saw a simple belief nets like this:
[image: Img]
which encodes $P(A,B,C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C)$. But then it says we can marginalize over C to erase C. Which means $\sum_c P(A,B,C)=\sum_c P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C)$. But what made me confused is that how can we write a mathematical justification for this. I wrote down one here:
$$\sum_c P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C)=\sum_c P(A|C) \sum_c P(B|C) \sum_c P(C)$$
But this does not make sense from the algebra perspective. I am really confused.
Thanks for any helpful reply.

Answer (score 2):

In general we have
$$
P(A,B,C) = P(A,B \mid C) P(C).
$$
But your picture seems to imply that $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent of $C$  and thus
$$
P(A,B \mid C) = P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C).
$$
Now summing both sides over $c$ we get
$$
\sum_{c} P(A,B,C) = \sum_{c} P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C) P(C).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So now we get $\sum_c P(A,B,C)=\sum_c P(A|C)P(B|C)P(C)$, but how can derive this formula$P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ from the formula above?

Comment: @SunChuanneng By the law of total probability the left hand side is $P(A,B)$. But the right hand side doesn't equal P(A)P(B) without further assumptions. Because conditional independence doesn't imply independence.